# No audio - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, sound, 15.10

My motherboard is a Gigabyte G1 Sniper M5
On the download page for said board, it shows they only provide drivers for windows systems.

I'm assuming it's a driver issue I've got. I've gone through all the standard audio troubleshooting and nothing.

EDIT:

Error message for running gnome-control-center:

```
(unity-control-center:3279): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: Unable to find stream for bar '(null)'

(unity-control-center:3279): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_output_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active output

(unity-control-center:3279): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_input_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active input
```

Error message for running sudo gnome-control-center:

```
** (gnome-control-center.real:3301): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher gufw (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center.real:3301): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)

(gnome-control-center.real:3301): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/lewis/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

Answer (score 0):

I only do ubuntu 14.04. But I have found no audio out problems are about the permissions given to /dev/snd and the files there. On my systems the files have permissions for user root and group audio.

Note no world permissions so a user must belong to group audio to have permission.

```
ls -l /dev/snd to see permissions.

.....@xen2[2145]ls -l /dev/snd
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Mar 22 17:42 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Mar 22 17:42 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Mar 22 17:42 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Mar 22 17:42 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Mar 22 17:42 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Mar 22 18:56 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Mar 22 17:42 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 22 17:42 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 22 17:42 timer

If your /dev/snd files have the same permissions 
grep audio /etc/group and see if you are in that group.  

I added my username to group audio with 
sudo usermod -a -G audio "myusername"
do not quote " your user name.

I use fvwm as a window manager and start gnome stuff in an xterm. Or Gnome-Terminial.

my quick test of sound
gnome-control-center sound see if the sound effect output. 
No then do it with sudo gnome-control-center sound and see if sound effects work. 
if it works for sudo or root and not for you then it is permissions.

I just installed 14.04 on my laptop using amd64 desktop iso on a usb.
but default it install unity.   Sound did work out of the box.
But there are not the gnome-control-center sound utility.
so I
sudo apt-get gnome   It installed lots of gnome utils .... also
it asked me to choose a window manager ligntdm or gdm.   I came with lightdm highlighted and I left it.    I will be installing xdm and then I will use it.
I suspect xdm is more generic than gdm or lightdm.
Then I ran
sudo gnome-control-center sound and under Sound Effects there was only the Default and it audio clicked as I tapped it with the mouse.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added my username to the list and ran gnome-control-center. In gnome-control-center, the "Test Sound" produces no output. I've added the message I get in terminal after running gnome-control-center to main post.

When I run sudo gnome-control-center, there is no sound option. I've added the error message I get for running this command in the main post also.

Comment: I asume by list you mean you added yourself or your username to /etc/group  file  to the audio group.    I don't use unity.   I also add gnome window manager to my systems.   sudo apt-get install gnome    I also don't use the gnome window manger but I use gnome utilities under   the fvwm2 window manager.  this is becoming a run on comment so I am going to add another answer.

Comment: I updated my original answer with you have to have the gnome window manager installed or at least some of the gnome utilities to use the gnome-control-center sound

Comment: I installed gnome and followed the instructions you added in your answer. I run sudo gnome-control-center and still no sound icon